# Grafana dashboard doesn't display custom legend value if prom query returns only one result

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

I have a prom query that returns my pvc usages if they are over a certain threshold in a Gauge chart.

Example:

`((kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes / kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes) * 100) >= 30`

This query returns:
`{endpoint="https-metrics", instance="89.247.325.217:10250", job="kubelet", namespace="postgres", node="pool-1c5r15h-4pwmenbjse", persistentvolumeclaim="data-postgres-postgresql-0", service="kube-prometheus-kubelet"}`

In my legend values field, I reference `{{persistentvolumeclaim}}`.

This works completely fine if the query returns multiple results. For example if I change the threshold of the query to `>=30`

(I overrode the display name for the pvc names, hence it shows "PVC: ...". The issue is also not related to the override, I tested it)

[Legend values displayed correctly]
[image]

Now if I change the threshold so that the query only returns one result, the label value is not displayed eventho it is being returned by the query. The label is showing when I choose the time series chart though. If I choose the Stat or Gauge chart the label is not displayed.

[Legend value not being displayed]
[image]

If I change the chart to the time series chart and remove the `{{persistentvolumeclain}}` reference from the legend, it clearly returns the result containing a `persistentvolumeclaim` field:

[result contains pvc field]
[image]

Does someone know if this is a grafana issue or might I have misconfigured something?

Tried explicitly overriding display name. Tried different chart types but it only works on the time series chart and state timeline chart.

Comment: I think it's deliberately hiding legend for a single Gauge. Probably because it's unconventional (to say the least) to have variable number of gauges, and for a single one there is no obvious need for legend. Have you considered using Stat panel instead?

Comment: @markalex the same issue applies to the stat panel unfortunately.

Comment: For Stat panel you can set Text mode to Value and Name, and always see legend.